# More technical details on the ongoing (alleged) Chinese cyberattacks

Tags: brute-force-attack

Recently, there has been [quite](http://www.ft.com/intl/cms/s/0/41f930e6-b69a-11e2-93ba-00144feabdc0.html#axzz2UsQXDMx4) a [lot](http://www.theatlanticwire.com/global/2013/05/china-hackers-pentagon/65628/) of [news](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/newsdesk/2013/05/political-scene-the-us-china-and-cyber-security.html) about the [Chinese](http://www.newyorker.com/reporting/2013/05/20/130520fa_fact_seabrook) compromising various US weapons systems and stealing military designs through "cyberwarfare". I am reading the news sources about these attacks, but popular news sites often refer to the technical details as "solving complicated mathematical problems" or just "attacks."

What cryptologic techniques are the Chinese [alleged to be] using to steal these weapons designs and compromise the US military system?  Can anyone provide more technical details or a reference to a more detailed, in-depth description?

Comment: I haven't been able to find a single article that references "solving complicated mathematical problems" available on the free internet (can't tell if the FT article says that as it is behind a paywall).

Comment: *cleaned up a few comments from a prior version of question*